# apk file debugging - React Native

Tags: java, android, react-native

I have a React Native App. It works fine in iOS and android.
Hence i have built the bundle for both. ios works fine.
Now my team has created the apk file and when they run it they are getting the below error:

[image]

I don't know which part of my code is causing this issue. 
How can I debug this apk and find out where is the error source?

I have watched a couple of videos on this so I know first I need to decode the apk file.
I did that successfully. I have my AndroidManifest.xml (changed to "debuggable:true"), got my Smali files, java files, etc.

Then I opened all that in Android Studio. I placed few breakpoints in my java files. Well it did not stop in any of those breakpoints

Android studio error:

**E/unknown:ReactNative: Exception in native call java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.String at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeArray.getString(Unknown Source:21) at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper$5.extractArgument(Unknown Source:0) at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper$5.extractArgument(Unknown Source:0) at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(Unknown Source:162) at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(Unknown Source:23) at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:0) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(Unknown Source:37) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)**

This is so so confusing!! How do I backtrack this error? I can understand my react native javascript errors but this is so confusing. Need some guidance Pleaseee help!!!

Comment: okay , for this types of error usually it comes from an unsupported library, or any such code, please traceback and try to comment out code and check.Try with the latest library you tried and commenting or uninstalling that

Answer (score 0):

You have a variable that is a type Double and you are using it as a String.

can you find any suspicious code and cast it to string by using `String(your_possible_double_var)`